# PHP Form seems to change action to a different script

Tags: php, html, mamp

I'm building a website that has a form that allows users to upload files, but the form seems to be going to the wrong place. I told it to go to *"upload.php"*, but instead it tries to go to *"â€śupload.php"*, which I did not include in the form action. It doesn't look like I added any unicode characters in the script. Any reason why this might be happening?

**Here's my form in index.html:**
https://pastebin.com/7PETk5Sy

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Deeper</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="titlebar">
  <img src="DeeperNetIcon.jpg"></img>
  <h1>DeeperNet</h1>
  <a href="http://oriondark7.com/deeper">Back to Deeper Homepage</a>
  <br/><br/>
  <form action="view.php" method="post">Search for World by ID: <input type="text" name="world">  <input type="submit" value="Search"></form>
  <br/>
  </div>
  <p color="white">Welcome to DeeperNet!</p>
  <div id="upload">
    <h1>Upload World to DeeperNet</h1>
    <form action=“upload.php” method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    World File:
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="file" name="world">
    <br/><br/>
    World Name:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br/>
    Description:
    <br/>
    <input type="textbox" name="desc">
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload World">
    </form>
    <br/>
  </div>

</body>
```

The index.html File has 2 Forms, the second form is the one I'm talking about.

**Here's my upload.php Script:**
https://pastebin.com/0FyuAX3Q

```
<?php
include("index.html");
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    if(isset($_FILES["world"])) {

        $world = $_FILES["world"];

        $name = $world["name"];
        $tmp_name = $world["tmp_name"];
        $size = $world["size"];
        $ext = explode('.', $name);
        $ext = strtolower(end($ext));

        $allowed = "deep";

        if ($ext == $allowed) {
            if ($size <= 300000) {
                $id = uniqid('', true);
                $destination = 'worlds/' . $id . '.' . $ext;
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destination)) {
                    echo '<br/>World: "' . $name . '" uploaded to DeeperNet!';
                    echo “<br/>World ID: ” . $id;
                    $info = fopen('worlds/' . $id . '.txt', 'w');
                    fwrite($info, $_POST['name'] . "\r\n");
                    fwrite($info, $_POST['desc']);
                    fclose($info);
                }
            }
        }
```

MAMP says I'm using PHP 7.0.8 if you're wondering.

Comment: Because `“` are not real quotes.

Comment: double quotes `"` not inverted commas

Comment: Sorry for being a bit off topic, but `“` are actually more _“real”_ quotes than `"` - but they are not valid for HTML attribute definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code with this as form accepts this  double quotes (")  not this one (“)

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I fixed that, but now it's giving me another error in Chrome: This page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Then there is an issue in upload.php file.